# glGetTexImage for GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP

Tags: opengl

I needed to save the depth cubemap to a file. I wrote the following code:

```
GLfloat* pixels = new GLfloat[width * height];
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, texture);
glGetTexImage(target, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, pixels);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, 0);
```

but it only works well with `target = GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X`

I'm using Debian Testing (buster/sid), NVGF 920mx

[image]

If this is a driver bug, how can I get around it? I will be grateful for help.

Comment: *"but it only works well with `target = GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X`"* What doesn't work with the other directions? Do you mean the orientation?

Comment: @Rabbid76 the remaining faces of cubemap were incorrect. The impression is that the data was corrupted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a driver bug. It was tested on other video cards, there was no problem. Also, a test was conducted on the same video card only under Windows - no problems were observed.